# Как правильно написать 2 Activity в манифесте

Tags: java, android

хочу определить в каком городе находится пользователь и вывести эту информацию на экран.
Cпрашиваю разрешения У пользователя на

1. ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   ```
2. ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   ```

> У меня есть java класc для определения местоположения пользователя "gps1.java"

Я на MainActivity написал код для меню состоящих из 3-фрагментов

при замене MainActivity на gps1 всё работает отлично но пропадает меню.И только показывает страницу из 3 фрагмента.при этом начинает спрашивать разрешение на использование геолокацию и даже показывает город где я нахожусь.но GPS1.JAVA добавить как Activity не дает результатов даже не спрашивает разрешение.Помогите пожалуйста если что-то мало напишите)

[image: скриншот по]

```
 <activity android:name=".gps1"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
```

Comment: приведите код который отвечает за показ активности, покажите где регулируется видимость нижнего меню, пока что сложно помочь только по скриншотам

Answer (score 1):

Там ничего сложного в манифесте

```
    <activity android:name=".Instruction"
        android:exported="true"
        />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```